# Python os.environ, Windows PATH, and Windows "System" variables

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

My Python script is trying to setup a Windows system, including the value of the environment variable PATH.

Windows appears to have two sets of places where it stores environment variables - "User variables" and "System variables". (To see what I mean in Win10, type "environment variables" into the Start menu, then click on the "Environment Variables..." button at the bottom right of that dialog.)

The PATH as seen by programs (example: `os.environ` in Python) appears to be a concatenation of the PATH system variable and the PATH user variable.

I'm trying to setup the User version of PATH, without affecting the System version.

My problem: When I use `os.environ('PATH') = value`, the PATH available to Python becomes the string in `value` only (what I meant for the User version of PATH), and the contents of the System PATH disappears. Then the rest of my Python script can't find the executables it needs.

I can think of several hacky workaounds, but what's the proper way to deal with this?

FWIW, here's what I use to set environment variables (including PATH) now:

```
def setEnvironmentVariable(name, value):
    '''Set an environment variable in both current and permanent environment '''
    os.environ[name] = value
    os.system('set '  + name + ' = ' + value)       # for this shell
    os.system('setx ' + name + ' "'  + value + '"') # for the permanent user environment
```

(Note os.system is using cmd.exe; I'm OK with using Powershell if that'll help.)

Comment: `os.environ('PATH') += ";" + value`

Comment: @Cid If I just want to *append* to PATH, that would be fine. But I also want to clear out any prior crud in the User PATH. Also, if that were run multiple times, it would add multiple copies of *value* to the PATH.

Comment: another cleaner way would be to split -> process your clearing things in the result-> join and replace

Comment: You can edit `HKCU\Environment\Path` as well (or `HKLM` if you want to edit system variable)

Comment: @Cid splitting/processing the variable (via registry or otherwise) is one of the "hacky" ideas I thought of. But it requires prior knowledge of what is likely to be in the System PATH variable. That seems likely to break on a differently-configured machine.